# Compare array with null elements

Tags: powershell

I have two array's having more that 500,000 values and need to compare to find the difference. Some of the values in the array are `$null`. When I am trying to do the following code and I getting an error `Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null`

Is there any work around for this issue or is there a better and faster way to find the difference? I am only interested in the count of variance/difference.

Thanks!

Example Code:

```
$objSource = @('a', $null, 'c')
$objTarget = @('a', 'b','c')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $objSource -DifferenceObject $objTarget | Measure
```

Error Message:

```
Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null . At line:4 char:32
+ Compare-Object -ReferenceObject <<<<  $objSource -DifferenceObject $objTarget
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValid     ationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft     .PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx) states that this would happen if the `-ReferenceObject` or `-DifferenceObject` were `$null` but does not really cover if the any elements of those objects are.

> NOTE: If the reference set or the difference set is null ($null), Compare-Object generates a terminating error.

Quick work around would be to replace those `$null` elements with a control character or something along those lines.

```
$objSource = @('a', $null, 'c') -replace "^$","null"
$objTarget = @('a', 'b','c') -replace "^$","null"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $objSource -DifferenceObject $objTarget
```

The `-replace` would remove those empty entries from the array with string "null". So we would have a visual indication of that data now. Unlikely that that text would be a natural element but you would have to be wary just the same. If null is not appropriate I would recommend bagel as a keyword!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
$objSource = @('a', $null, 'c')
$objTarget = @('a', 'b','c')
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ([string[]]$objSource) -DifferenceObject ([string[]]$objTarget) | Measure
```

Comment: Yes, this works but the result is always 2. I would like to find the variance count.